# Graphing individual points on a grouped violin plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

After a good amount of looking, I can't seem to find the exact answer to my question, so I figured I'd ask.

I want to make a grouped violin plot of a timecourse I have with two conditions ("Control RNAi" and "mex-6 RNAi") using ggplot2. Each of the data points comes from 3 different replicates ("Worm" factor in dataframe), so the dataframe format I have looks like this (with "mean_mex6" being the plotted Y value):

| mean_mex6 | RNAi | Time | Worm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.4102356 | Control RNAi | 2hr | worm1 |
| 0.8332575 | Control RNAi | 2hr | worm1 |
| 2.5093177 | Control RNAi | 2hr | worm1 |
| 0.8792359 | Control RNAi | 2hr | worm1 |
| 1.2570116 | Control RNAi | 2hr | worm1 |
| 1.0671826 | Control RNAi | 2hr | worm1 |

There are many more lines in the dataframe, but the data I showed you above are just some datapoints that came from "worm1" on "Control RNAi" at the "2hr" timepoint.

I want all the individual points plotted in each RNAi group on the violin plot, but I want them plotted so that every datapoint from each "Worm" sample is a different color from the other worms. I have been able to create a grouped violin plot where all the individual points are plotted, but not color coded for each individual worm sample:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(compiled_allhours, aes(x=Time, y=mean_mex6, colour=RNAi)) + 
  geom_violin(trim=FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("2hr", "4hr","6hr", "8hr","24hr")) + ##This chooses which data to plot and orders them
  geom_quasirandom(aes(x=Time, y=mean_mex6, colour = RNAi), dodge.width = 0.9, varwidth = TRUE) +
  ggtitle(expression(paste(italic("mex-6"), " nuclear signal", " - WT"))) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + ##Centers the title of the plot
  xlab("Time") +
  ylab(expression(paste("normalized ", italic("mex-6"), " nuclear signal (A.U.)")))
```

I included an image of the plot that this makes.[Plot 1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvfYW.png

If I try to color the individual points by worm, this is what happens:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(compiled_allhours, aes(x=Time, y=mean_mex6, colour=RNAi)) + 
  geom_violin(trim=FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("2hr", "4hr","6hr", "8hr","24hr")) + ##This chooses which data to plot and orders them
  geom_quasirandom(aes(x=Time, y=mean_mex6, colour = Worm), dodge.width = 0.9, varwidth = TRUE) +
  ggtitle(expression(paste(italic("mex-6"), " nuclear signal", " - WT"))) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + ##Centers the title of the plot
  xlab("Time") +
  ylab(expression(paste("normalized ", italic("mex-6"), " nuclear signal (A.U.)")))
```

[Plot 2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVJwG.png

So basically, I want the second plot, but with all those points merged into the violin plot as is shown in the first graph. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that different groupings are applied for the `geom_violin` and the `geom_quasirandom` in your second plot. Therefore the points and the violins are "dodged" differently and do not align with each other.

To get your desired result you have to make use to the `group` aesthetic, i.e. group by both `Time` and `RNAi` using e.g. `interaction`.

Additionally instead of mapping `Worm` on color I mapped it on `fill` (Made more sense to me as Worm and RNai are different variables) and used filled points (`shape=21`) which gives different legends. But feel free to change that by switching back to `color`.

Using a more realistic random dataset including "all" options for the different variables try this:

```r
set.seed(42)
compiled_allhours <- data.frame(
  mean_mex6 = runif(200),
  RNAi = sample(c("Control RNAi", "mex-6 RNAi"), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Time = sample(c("2hr", "4hr", "6hr", "8hr", "24hr"), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Worm = sample(c("worm1", "worm2", "worm3"), 200, replace = TRUE)
)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbeeswarm)

ggplot(compiled_allhours, aes(x=Time, y=mean_mex6, group=interaction(RNAi, Time))) + 
  geom_violin(aes(color = RNAi), trim=FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("2hr", "4hr","6hr", "8hr","24hr")) + ##This chooses which data to plot and orders them
  geom_quasirandom(aes(x=Time, y=mean_mex6, fill = Worm), shape = 21, color = "transparent", dodge.width = 0.9, varwidth = TRUE) +
  ggtitle(expression(paste(italic("mex-6"), " nuclear signal", " - WT"))) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + ##Centers the title of the plot
  xlab("Time") +
  ylab(expression(paste("normalized ", italic("mex-6"), " nuclear signal (A.U.)")))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Awesome, thank you! This looks really nice! I have one more question if you don't mind!

When I run this on my data, I get exactly what I asked for, but the dots are overlaid on top of each other in worm order (i.e. so if worm 1 is blue and worm 2 is magenta, it will first graph all the blue points, then it will cover the blue points with the magenta points). Is there a way to get geom_quasirandom to plot it so the points are randomly piled on top of eachother (i.e. so it's not all magenta on top of blue, but rather a mix of both)? Couldn't find this info in geom_quasirandom. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Concerning the issue with the over plotting. The points are plotted in the order they appear in your dataset. Therefore you could try with reshuffling your dataset, e.g. `sample_n(compiled_allhours, nrow(compiled_allhours))` will reorder your df randomly. Additionally one strategy to deal with overplotting is to add some opacity, i.e. you could add e.g. `alpha=.5` to geom_quasirandom.